# Need help Openvpn

Tags: vpn, openvpn

I want to install an openvpn, but I have a problem :

```
dpkg -i openvpn-as-2.0.20-Ubuntu.amd_64.deb
```

and I get the following message :

```
dpkg: error processing archive openvpn-as-2.0.20-Ubuntu14.amd_64.deb (--install):
 cannot access archive: No such file or directory
Errors were encountered while processing:
 openvpn-as-2.0.20-Ubuntu14.amd_64.deb
```

I have try things, but i don't understand why...
The directory of my file is :
C:\Users\Jeje73\Downloads\openvpn-as-2.0.20-Ubuntu14.amd_64.deb
(I use Putty - disk D)

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You need to add the filepath like this:

```
dpkg -i ~/Desktop/somefolder/openvpn-as-2.0.20-Ubuntu.amd_64.deb
```

`~` this is your home folder. When refering to program files you always need to add the complete path to it, I normally use the TAB function to find the correct path faster. The TAB function in the terminal is used as an auto complete.

Always try to read the error output and try to understand wahts wrong, here it says it can't find it, and It's because you have no file path.

Good luck!